# Notation of quotient groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I'm determining the quotient group of $(E,+)$ in $(Z,+)$ where E is even int. and Z is int.

I know sort of what is happening, I split the group $Z$ into evens and odds (2 sets) and as we are under addition, an element is either even or odd. I don't know the notation for writing this as a group though?

As an added question: How do I determine the quotient group of $(Z,+) $ in $(Q,+)$?

Comment: The notation is $Z/E$.

Comment: Hm. If I am asked to determine a quotient group of these two groups, it can't be enough to simply write $Z / E$ can it?

Comment: You asked about the notation, and this is what I gave you. In the former case, this is isomorphic to a familiar group. How many groups with two elements do you know? In the latter case, I can't say I know a description in entirely elementary terms simpler than ${\bf Q}/{\bf Z}$.

Comment: It says: Determine the quotient group of $(\mathbb{Z} , +)$ in $(\mathbb{Q} , +)$.

Is there no way to describe it other than to simply denote it?

Comment: That, and describing the elements and the group operation. But I can't think of any simpler definition of a group isomorphic to this one.

Comment: @tomasz: Regarding a group isomorphism: The group $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to the "rational unit circle" with multiplication. (Even though denoting this is not really simpler than the original group.)